# Firebase and Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this app I send the user's current location to firebase and display on the screen. I'm just having trouble removing the previous marker when I update the position.

I used this code:

```
if (marker! = null) {
    marker.remove ();
}
```

When I use this code it only looks like a 1 marker and the others disappear from the screen.

Can someone help me?

```
@Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Localizacao localizacao = chatSnapshot.getValue(Localizacao.class);
                    Double latitude = localizacao.getLatitude();
                    Double longitude = localizacao.getLongitude();
                    String giro = localizacao.getGiro();

                    if (marker != null){
                        marker.remove();
                    }

                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int n = rand.nextInt(20);

                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .flat(true)
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .rotation(Float.parseFloat(giro))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_car))
                            .title(String.valueOf(n)));

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

DATABASE IMAGE:

[image]

PRINT: 
[image]

Comment: Is there just one marker and you want to remove it - then add another marker once the location has been updated?

Comment: @Barns52 I want to display both markers. if I remove the marker.remove (); it display the two markers normally the problem is when the location is updating the is getting "TRACE" of the old positions of the markers understand?

Comment: If google translate did not fail me. You don't want to remove the markers, you just want to continue adding markers in order to have a 'path' of markers tracing the users path?

Comment: @Barns52 No, I want to display only the two markers and their current positions without any traces.

Comment: @Barns52 I added a print of the problem.

Comment: How did the solution work in field?

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with firebase database, but if I understand your example then your database only has two rows of data at any one time? And that `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` will return both of these rows when any one of the data values is changed?

If that is the case try putting `mMap.clear()` outside your `foreach` loop. That way all markers (unfortunately, any other object you have added eg. Circle) will be removed from the Map.

```
@Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //Remove all markings from Map
                mMap.clear();

                // Now your foreach loop will pick up the two rows and add new markers to the map
                for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Localizacao localizacao = chatSnapshot.getValue(Localizacao.class);
                    Double latitude = localizacao.getLatitude();
                    Double longitude = localizacao.getLongitude();
                    String giro = localizacao.getGiro();

                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int n = rand.nextInt(20);

                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .flat(true)
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .rotation(Float.parseFloat(giro))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_car))
                            .title(String.valueOf(n)));

                }    

            }
```

Comment: Thank you, apparently its right I'll test on the field by taking a drive.